# SML List dublets

Tags: list, sml

I need a function that will take a list as for example `[1,1,2,2]` and return preferably `[2,2]` or `[(2*1),(2*2)]` but `[2,0,2,0]` will suffice as long as it is possibly to see how many doublets there are in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could try sorting the list first using [ListMergeSort](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/listsort.html)'s sort function. Once you have a sorted list, it's straightforward to find the frequencies of each element using a simple recursive function.

Comment: Its the "simple recursive function" that buggers me out a bit, i can't seem to remember how the heck i get it to do what i want. Function would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, you'll need to keep track of the last element you've seen, a list of the frequencies, and the rest of the list you're searching through. If you make those things parameters to your function, then you can recursively build up the frequency list as you go, depending on whether the next element of the input list is the same as the last element you've seen. Does that help?

Comment: It does but i would assume your function would be something like
fun dubs n (x::y::xs) = if x = y then dubs n+1 (y::xs) else dubs n (x::xs) or something.